# Flutter cannot running with Sentry on Xcode version 15.0.1

Tags: flutter, xcode, dart, sentry

I hard to try running flutter application with sentry on Xcode version 15.0
it's almost showing message like that:

Modules Issue (Xcode): Import of C++ module 'Darwin.Mach' appears within extern "C" language linkage specification
/Users/xxx/xxx/Projects/flutter_project/ios/Pods/Sentry/Sources/SentryCrash/Recording/Tools/SentryCrashMachineContext.h:35:0

Modules Issue (Xcode): Import of C++ module 'Darwin.POSIX.sys.types' appears within extern "C" language linkage specification
/xxx/xxx/Desktop/Projects/flutter_project/ios/Pods/Sentry/Sources/SentryCrash/Recording/Tools/SentryCrashStackCursor.h:35:0

Did you face before?

Comment: This could be a problem with the SDK, could you please create a ticket: https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-dart/issues/new?assignees=&labels=Platform%3A+Dart%2Cbug&projects=&template=BUG_REPORT.yml ? A small reproduction app can help the engineers figure out what's wrong

Answer (score 0):

### Upgrade

Upgrade `sentry_flutter` to version **7.16.1**:

```bash
flutter pub upgrade
```

This issue now solved in this [PR](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-cocoa/pull/3538)